# Len (rec/tot) in WAL in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm learning how WAL is working in postgresql, but I don't really understand how is the len(record) value obtained, and where I can find the record.

For tests I've done such inserts:

```
INSERT INTO int_table (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO int_table (field1, field2, field3, field4) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO int_table (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (1, 1, 1);
```

After with the help of pg_waldump.exe I've gottent the wal dump:

```
rmgr: Heap        len (rec/tot):     79/    79, ...
rmgr: Heap        len (rec/tot):     75/    75, ...
rmgr: Heap        len (rec/tot):     71/    71, ...
```

So, I can see that the difference between records is 4 bytes (one int value). However, I'm curious about the information contained in the other bytes. For example, the last record has 59 bytes of additional information, along with 4 + 4 + 4 bytes for three values (1, 1, 1).

So, my question is where and why these 59 bytes are written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is header data with info like the tablespace, database, file, block/page, and offset at which the change should be applied.

It is hard to see what you hope to accomplish here that won't involve reading the source code, so why not just go read the source code to figure out what the fields are?